# Response failing in httpx but not in requests

Tags: python, post, python-requests, httpx

I am making a POST request to a URL using '**httpx**' library. However, I get a ***401 unauthorized error*** with my below request

```
cert = os.path.realpath('./certs/certificate.pem')
key = os.path.realpath('./certs/key.pem')
context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.load_cert_chain(certfile=cert, keyfile=key, password=os.getenv('PASSWORD', ''))
response = httpx.post(
            url=my_url,
            data={'client_id': os.getenv('USER', '')},
            verify=context
        )
token = response.json()['access_token']
```

In contrast, if I make the same request using '**requests**' library, then it succeeds and I get the response. Below is my request

```
cert = os.path.realpath('./certs/certificate.pem')
key = os.path.realpath('./certs/key2.pem')
certificate = (cert, key)
response = requests.post(my_url, cert=certificate, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(os.getenv('USER', ''), os.getenv('PASSWORD', '')))
token = response.json()['access_token']
```

May I know what am I missing here?

Comment: Your `httpx` request doesn't seem to be using HTTP Basic Auth, where the `requests` one does. See the httpx docs https://www.python-httpx.org/quickstart/#authentication

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by adding user-agent in the request header.

```
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.3"
```

Some servers check the User-Agent header to see if the request comes from a known client. Since httpx and requests might have different default User-Agent headers, it's possible that the server may be blocking requests from unfamiliar user-agents. You can try setting the User-Agent header to mimic a common browser or use the one from the requests package.